# Do I have to unlock heroes in Overwatch?

Tags: overwatch

Overwatch is a multiplayer first person shooter. I preordered the standard edition of the game, but I don't know whether it's like Dota 2 where all heroes are available, or if it's just like League of Legends where I have to pay IP to play a character.

Comment: Hi Mavis! remember you can 'accept' an answer if you believe it adequately answers your question. Just click the checkmark beneath the answer's vote count :). It will award the answerer (and yourself!) some extra reputation points. This can also be changed or undone at any point if you feel another answer is more relevant, or if the accepted answer is out of date. :)

Comment: As a side note, Overwatch is not a MOBA, it's more of a team shooter such as Team Fortress. Heroes do not level up, there are no items to buy, and no minions to kill while walking down lanes.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

No. All of the heroes in Overwatch are (and will be, in the case of future additions) unlocked and at full power from the start. The only things you unlock through either time or money are cosmetics, such as skins, sprays, or victory poses.

Comment: This is why Blizzard is so awesome.

Answer (score 9):

In addition, in a [Developer Update video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OKG8Yx6F7uc), Blizzard has confirmed that future heroes other than the original 21 released down the line will be available as free content packs, and not paid DLC releases.